# Pandas: Updating the Position of Values in a Row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following DataFrame and its separated by 2 teams `P` and `E` and each player and their position are related data so should be kept together `P1` & `P1_Position`.

I'm interested in:

- Viewing specific players from each team `P: [('T', '3'), ('K', '2')]`
  and `E: [('N', '1')]`

  I would like to order each row with respect to the players im
  interested in viewing, so that `('T', '3'), ('K', '2')` and `('N', '1')` at at the beginning of their teams.

| P1 | P1_Position | P2 | P2_Position | P3 | P3_Position | E1 | E1_Position | E2 | E2_Position | E3 | E3_Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H | 1 | K | 2 | T | 3 | H | 3 | N | 1 | S | 5 |
| K | 2 | T | 3 | Y | 4 | A | 2 | H | 3 | N | 1 |
| K | 2 | T | 3 | Y | 4 | AK | 4 | H | 3 | N | 1 |
| K | 2 | T | 3 | Y | 4 | AK | 4 | A | 2 | N | 1 |

The resulting DataFrame would look something like:

| P1 | P1_Position | P2 | P2_Position | P3 | P3_Position | E1 | E1_Position | E2 | E2_Position | E3 | E3_Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **T** | **3** | **K** | **2** | H | 1 | **N** | **1** | H | 3 | S | 5 |
| **T** | **3** | **K** | **2** | Y | 4 | **N** | **1** | H | 3 | A | 2 |
| **T** | **3** | **K** | **2** | Y | 4 | **N** | **1** | H | 3 | AK | 4 |
| **T** | **3** | **K** | **2** | Y | 4 | **N** | **1** | A | 2 | AK | 4 |

The purpose of the ordering is to have a consistent formatting when attempting to perform a groupby operation E.G All players of interest are at the far left of each entry.

My current thought process is that I will need to use `rename(columns={})` across each row using `apply`, but my first reaction to that is its going to be slow.

```
def reorderrows(row, players, enemies):
    doSomething(row)

desiredrows = desiredrows.apply(reorderrows, axis=1, players=players, enemies=enemies)
```

Is there a good way of enforcing that ordering given that each list P: [('T', '3'), ('K', '2')]`and`E: [('N', '1')]` could include up to 3 players?

**Example DataFrame:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'P1': ['H', 'K', 'K', 'K'],
                       'P1_Position': [1,2,2,2],
                       'P2': ['K', 'T', 'T', 'T'],
                       'P2_Position': [2,3,3,3],
                       'P3': ['T', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'],
                       'P3_Position': [3,4,4,4],
                       'E1': ['H', 'A', 'AK', 'AK'],
                       'E1_Position': [3,2,4,4],
                       'E2': ['N', 'H', 'H', 'A'],
                       'E2_Position': [1,3,3,2],
                       'E3': ['S', 'N', 'N', 'N'],
                       'E3_Position': [5,1,1,1],})
```

Comment: That position for player 'T` is 3, so any modification in the ordering of the player 'T' should also result in the same change for its position (3). The first table is the 'groundtruth' if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create dictionary for specify `P/E` players and convert to `DataFrame` with `index` column for sorting:

```
d = {'P': [('T', '3'), ('K', '2')], 'E': [('N', '1')]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame([(k, *x) for k, v in d.items() for x in v],
                   columns=['key','_','Position']).reset_index()
print (df1)
   index key  _ Position
0      0   P  T        3
1      1   P  K        2
2      2   E  N        1
```

Then reshape DataFrame by split columns names by `_` to `MultiIndex`, rename `NaN`s to `_` and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), extract column `key` by non numeric column from original columns names, convert `Position` to strings and use left join by helper `DataFrame`, sorting and reshape back by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with count original indices and columns names:

```
f = lambda x:  '_' if pd.isna(x) else x
df2 = (df.pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.str.split('_', expand=True), axis=1))
          .rename(columns=f)
          .stack(0)
          .reset_index()
          .assign(key=lambda x: x.level_1.str.extract('^(\D+)', expand=False),
                   Position = lambda x: x.Position.astype(str))
          .merge(df1, how='left')
          .sort_values('index')
          .assign(i = lambda x: x.groupby('key').cumcount(),
                   level_0 = lambda x: x['i'] % len(df),
                   level_1 = lambda x: x['key'] + (x['i'] // len(df) + 1).astype(str))
          .set_index(['level_0','level_1'])[['_','Position']].rename(columns={'_':''})
          .unstack()
          .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis([f'{b}_{a}'.strip('_') for a,b in x.columns], axis=1))
          .reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
          )
```

---

```
print (df2)
        P1 P1_Position P2 P2_Position P3 P3_Position E1 E1_Position E2  \
level_0                                                                  
0        T           3  K           2  H           1  N           1  H   
1        T           3  K           2  Y           4  N           1  S   
2        T           3  K           2  Y           4  N           1  A   
3        T           3  K           2  Y           4  N           1  H   

        E2_Position  E3 E3_Position  
level_0                              
0                 3  AK           4  
1                 5   H           3  
2                 2  AK           4  
3                 3   A           2
```

Comment: This is gonna take some time to go through but wow you're a monster, that was quick. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jack - sure, more important is same column names like in your sample data (pattern P1, P1_Position) and default `RangeIndex` in `print (df.index)`, then solution should working well.